# Change the inference by adding a type assertion in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

From: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference

> TypeScript doesn’t assume the assignment of `1` to a field which
> previously had `0` is an error. Another way of saying this is that
> `obj.counter` must have the type `number`, not `0`, because types are
> used to determine both *reading* and *writing* behavior.
>
> The same applies to strings:
>
> ```
> const req = { url: "https://example.com", method: "GET" };
> handleRequest(req.url, req.method);
>
> // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"GET" | "POST"'.
> ```

I thought "GET" is a default value assigned to variable 'method' of the object 'req'. What is the error saying?

> 1. You can change the inference by adding a type assertion in either  location:
>
>    ```
>    // Change 1:
>    const req = { url: "https://example.com", method: "GET" as "GET" };
>    // Change 2
>    handleRequest(req.url, req.method as "GET");
>    ```
>
>    Change 1 means “I intend for `req.method` to always have the *literal
>    type* `"GET"`”, preventing the possible assignment of `"GUESS"` to
>    that field after. Change 2 means “I know for other reasons that
>    `req.method` has the value `"GET"`“.

What do they mean by adding a type assertion in this case?

What is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hover over `req`, you'll see that `method` is a string. The types have been "widened". You have to find a way to tell Typescript not to do that. One of these is using [`const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```
const req = { url: "https://example.com", method: "GET" } as const;
```

Or you can explicitly say that `method` is either "GET" or "POST".

```
const req: { url: string, method: "GET" | "POST" } = { url: "https://example.com", method: "GET" as "GET" };
```

or using type assertion like you did `as`. (We are often told not to use type assertions but that's a good use case)

This would work as well

```
const req = { url: "https://example.com", method: "GET" as const }; // const just on method
```

This little example will help you understand better what's happening:

```
let num = 3 //number since you can assign something else to num
const num = 3 //3 since it's a const (not supposed to change)
```

Comment: Oh, so the overall idea is to make the argument stay what it is and never allow its value to change? How is `method: "GET" | "POST"` different from `method: "GET"` in your second code example?

Comment: `const req = { url: "https://example.com", method: "GET" } as const;` Will this not make url also const? We won't want that?

Comment: `We are often told not to use type assertions` Why is that so?

Comment: And what is the meaning of this error: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"GET" | "POST"'`

Comment: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"GET" | "POST"'`. `handleRequest` expects either 'GET' or 'POST', yet `req.method` is a `string` because when you initialize `req`, the type of `method` has been widened, it just says that `method` is a string. And you can't pass whatever string you want to `handleRequest`. What if you pass 'foo' to `handleRequest`? Adding a `as const` will tell Typescript that you know that this value won't change. If you try to set method to 'POST' afterwards, you'll have an error: `POST can't be assigned to GET`.

Comment: `We are often told not to use type assertions` Why is that so? Well, with type assertions, you can do this: `const foo: string = "foo"
const bar = foo as "bar"`. Does Typescript complain? No. Is that correct. Nope. Type assertions are used to let Typescript know that you know better than him, which is hardly ever the case...

Comment: In my second code example, you could have typed method: "GET". But with method: "GET" | "POST", you can change it later to "POST" if you will. handleRequest expects either anyway.

Comment: `const req = { url: "https://example.com", method: "GET" } as const;` yes, this will turn all properties into consts but beware, only at the type level!

Comment: `string` was too wide a type, `as` was used to narrow it down to what it actually is and will stay, 'GET' or 'GET' | 'POST' not any other string.

Comment: I'll go with `as const`. Why? Again, you can do this: `const req = { url: "https://example.com", method: "GET" as "POST" };` Typescript won't complain but this is completely wrong. In the end, what you actually pass to `handleRequest` is "GET" not "POST".

Answer (score 1):

When creating `req`, you're basically creating an object with an `url: string` and `method: string`. Here's an example equal to your code:

```js
interface Request {
  url: string;
  method: string;
}
const req: Request = { url: "https://example.com", method: "GET" };
handleRequest(req.url, req.method);
```

but this way, you can't ensure that `method` is GET or POST, so if handleRequest expects one of those values it will complain if you pass a "string", which could equal to anything.

A solution could be to define a type for the req, for example:

```js
interface Request {
  url: string;
  method: 'GET' | 'POST';
}

// or using 'type' if you prefer
// type Request = {
//   url: string;
//   method: 'GET' | 'POST';
// }

const req: Request = { url: "https://example.com", method: "GET" };
handleRequest(req.url, req.method);
```